# Datasets of conversations of people in text format which have been labelled positive and negative

Tags: dataset, sentiment-analysis, naivebayes

I am currently doing a project on sentiment analysis. For this, I am searching for datasets of conversations of people in text format which have been labelled positive and negative. Can someone give me the links of such data sets.

Answer (score 0):

There are some good data sets with sentiment tags, but they are not from conversations.
Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24620559/5575289) to see some of them.

Another good corpus for sentiment analysis that is also used for question answering (QA) is [MPQA](http://mpqa.cs.pitt.edu/).

Answer (score 0):

A good dataset is downloadable from Stanford CoreNLP website (http://nlp.stanford.edu/sentiment/, then look at the box "Dataset downloads" on the right). This dataset is labelled at different levels (single word, phrases, entire sentences): if you only look for a sentence-level annotation you can simply take the outermost label of every sentence.